# Does Eclipse require a separate android project for unit tests?

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to add my AndroidTests to an existing project and run it from eclipse. I do not want to have a separate Eclipse project for the tests.

Is this possible?

When I try, Eclipse complains that uses-library instrumentation is required, which effectively means that an Android project cannot run its instrumentation tests if they are within the same project.

Using gradle, I can place my Android test code within the same project as the source production code, but I cannot do the same with Eclipse.

This leads to a disconnect where there ends up being 2x as many Android projects just to run in Eclipse, when gradle can handle single projects just fine.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: `I do not want to have a separate Eclipse project for the tests.` why not?

Comment: Eclipse does not support separate source folder for main code and test code, so you always need to use a separate project. This is not specific to Android.

Comment: njzk2: More projects makes code harder to manage, plus gradle can build a combined project fine, so my IDE should be able to do it too!
Xavier: I believe this is not true really, in a normal Java project Eclipse has source and junit test folders within the same project. It's just awkward that Android Eclipse projects do not support the same mode

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

If the project creates an Android library project, then yes. If the project creates an Android application, then no. An Eclipse project basically creates one APK output, which can *either* be a test project (perhaps incorporating code from a library) or an application, but not both.